# Accomplishing tricky layout in css grid or flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I need to accomplish a certain responsive layout from a sequence of div tags.  Below is the html I need to work with:

```
<div class="container">
  <div>1</id>
  <div>2</id>
  <div>3</id>
  <div>4</id>
  <div>5</id>
  <div>6</id>
  <div>7</id>
  <div>8</id>
  <div>9</id>
</div>
```

On larger screens it should only 4 columns, where columns 4-7 are displayed in a mini grid of it's own and where columns 8 and above are simply hidden.

[image: For larger screens]

On smaller screen, it should simply display a sequence of columns without any special arrangement, this part is straight forward so I shouldn't need help with this part

[image: On smaller screens]

My preference is to use css grid system is possible.  If not I would be open to using flexbox.

It's important no nested div are used unless they can be easily be expanded via css for smaller screens to display in the format shown above.

Is the above possible? All my attempts falling short.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make the bigger one take 2 rows and 2 columns:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column; /* a column flow */
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr; /* equal width columns */
}

.container>* {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 20px;
  aspect-ratio: 1; /* keep the elements square */
}

/* on big screens*/
@media (min-width: 700px) {
   /* make the first 3 bigger */
  .container> :nth-child(-n + 3) {
    grid-area: span 2/span 2;
  }
  /* hide from the 8th elements */
  .container> :nth-child(n + 8) {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This almost works, but unfortunately the whole grid seems to be limited in size.  I need the whole grid to occupy 100% of the parent div.  I couldn't get this to occur with your code sadly

Comment: @MusaffarPatel *need the whole grid to occupy 100% of the parent div.* --> that's what my code is doing

Comment: @ Temani Aif, you are correct, my mistake.   This is an excellent answer which I doubt I would have been able to arrive to myself.

Comment: A Could you explain exactly what the grid-auto-flow: column is doing in the content of the layout?

Comment: @MusaffarPatel it creates a horizontal layout (place items in columns) instead the default vertical one (place items in rows)